# Deleting nth element from a list Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I haven been set this task below:

> You are the captain of a sailing vessel and you and your crew have been captured by pirates. The pirate captain has all of you standing in a circle on the deck of his ship trying to decide in which order you should walk the plank. Eventually he decides on the following method:
>
> (a) The pirate captain asks you to pick a number N.
>
> (b) The first person to walk the plank will be the Nth person
>   (starting from you).
>
> (c) The captain will then continue around the circle forcing every Nth
>   person to walk the plank.
>
> (d) Once there is only one person left, that person will be given
>   freedom.
>
> For example: The crew consists of: Andrew, Brenda, Craig, Deidre,
>   Edward, Felicity, Greg and Harriet. Andrew selects N=2. The crew will
>   walk the plank in the order: Brenda, Deidre, Felicity, Harriet, Craig,
>   Greg, Edward. Andrew will be given freedom.

I have found a question on here relating to this task with answers but I was wondering where I am going wrong in my code and it must be possible to do without using modules which have been used in previous answers.

Heres what I have so far:

```
def survivor(names, step):
    next = step

    while len(names) > 1:
        names.pop(next)
        next = next + step - 1
        if next > len(names):
            next = next - len(names)

    return names[0]
```

And heres the error:

```
Pirates.survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Pirates.py", line 30, in survivor
    names.pop(next)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Comment: try `next = (next + step - 1)%len(names)` and you van get rid of the `next > len(names)` but yeah next is a terrible variable name ... also Im not sure if you need the -1 part in it

Comment: In the pseudo code we were given we was told to use the variable next but thanks for pointing that out to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because counting in computer science starts at 0, you need to initially set `next` in the same manner as you update it, i.e.

```
next = step - 1
```

In the example given, you are running using `N=2` and should return Brenda, but if you don't decrement the step by 1 you would pop `'Craig'` first. Making this change makes your code run and output the correct result on the example given.

Another change I'd recommend is using the modulo operator to ensure that `next` is always a valid index of `names`. It is much more concise and arguably easier to understand:

```
next = (next + step - 1) % len(names)
```

Putting this all together you have the following:

```
def survivor(names, step):
    next = step-1

    while len(names) > 1:
        print "-", names.pop(next), "walked"
    next = (next + step - 1) % len(names)

    return names[0]

print survivor(["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"], 2), "survived!"
```

Output:

```
- Brenda walked
- Deidre walked
- Felicity walked
- Harriet walked
- Craig walked
- Greg walked
- Edward walked
Andrew survived!
```

Finally, as has been pointed out elsewhere, don't name your variables  after built-in functions like `next`.

Comment: also use modulo instead of checking if `next > len(names)` as an aside shouldnt it be `if next >= len(names)`  ...since `a[len(a)]`will raise an exception about index not existing?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: good point, added!

Answer (score 0):

Your index error means that your code is trying to access an index in your list that does not exist. When I print out the `next` variable at the end of every while loop iteration, I get this:

```
5
1
3
1
3
```

Since python begins it's indexing at `0`, and since you only have 3 elements in your list at this point, it looks for `names[3]` but your list only goes up to `names[2]`

Also, I wouldn't use `next`  as a variable since it's a keyword.